# How do I check membership of items in a dict and list, within nested for loops?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

Trying to make this work is making my head spin:
I have an ordered dict:

```
OrderedDict([('key', {'keyword': {'blue', 'yellow'}), ('key1', {'keyword': {'lock', 'door'})])
```

I have a list of `potential_matches`: `[red, blue, one]`

I want to order these potential matches into one of two lists:
`correct = []` or `incorrect = []`

If the potential match is a keyword of one of the keys in the dict, then it goes in `correct`, else it goes in `incorrect`.

Result of this example should be:
`correct = [blue]`, `incorrect = [red, one]`

Here is what I tried:

```
correct = []  
incorrect = []  
for word in potential_matches:
    for key, value in ordered_dict.items():
        if word in value["keyword"] and word not in correct:
            correct.append(word)
        elif word not in value["keyword"] and word not in correct and word not in incorrect:
            incorrect.append(word)
```

the lists cannot have overlap and must have unique items, that's why there are so many checks in the `elif`.
It's close, but what ends up happening is that the incorrect list will still have items from the correct list.

How can I solve this as efficiently as possible?

I made it sound a bit complicated, but essentially, all remaining words that are not a match should simply go to the other list. This would require one full run through the `potential_match` list & dict, though, I think..

Comment: Your example seems to work fine: https://repl.it/repls/PeruBlackMineral

Comment: @AlexHall not working locally.. strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic works correctly when I run it, so there may be some logic which you have not supplied causing the error.

But, since you are working with collections of unique items, you can more efficiently implement your logic using `set` rather than `list`.

In addition, instead of cycling through `potential_matches`, loop through your dictionary and add items to a `correct` set. This reduces your complexity from O(*m* * *n*) to O(*n*), i.e. number of elements in lowest level dictionary values.

Then, at the very end, use `set.difference`, or syntactic sugar `-`, to calculate the `incorrect` set. Here's a demo:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('key', {'keyword': {'blue', 'yellow'}}),
                 ('key1', {'keyword': {'lock', 'door'}})])

potential_matches = {'red', 'blue', 'one'}

correct = set()
for v in d.values():
    for w in v['keyword']:
        if w in potential_matches:
            correct.add(w)

incorrect = potential_matches - correct
```

Result:

```
print(correct, incorrect, sep='\n')

{'blue'}
{'one', 'red'}
```

A more efficient version of this is possible via a `set` comprehension:

```
potential_matches = {'red', 'blue', 'one'}
correct = {w for v in d.values() for w in v['keyword'] if w in potential_matches}
incorrect = potential_matches - correct
```

Note that the structure of the nested set comprehension is aligned with how the verbose nested `for` loop is written.